# How to keep link to cells from messing up when I duplicate a sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Ok, so let's say my sheet name is bobob, and I make a link to go to cell a50, the link will automatically change to bobob!a50. This means that when I duplicate the sheet, and the new sheet is called "copy of bobob", the link will still be bobob!a50, and when I press it, it will take me to the original sheet.

How can I make it just link to the cell of the sheet I'm in. regardless of if I duplicate the sheet and/or change the name. So that when the sheet is duplicated, the link will take me to a50 cell of the sheet that the link is clicked.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. If i understand you correctly you want to refer to a cell in current sheet? Is just cell coordinates (a50) without sheet reference good enough?

Comment: When you say "make a link" I assume you mean [Link to data in a spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308662?hl=en), correct?

Comment: @KrzysztofDołęgowski sorry ill clarify, so lets say i click on a cell and click insert link, then i can choose to link a cell in that sheet, so that when i click it, it will take me to the linked cell. but when i do this it will automatically add the sheet name to the link, so if i was to... say... copy the link to another sheet and click it, it would take me to the cell in the original sheet. i want it so that whatever sheet the formula is in, it will take me to the linked cell "IN THAT SHEET".

Comment: @andrewjames yes thats exactly what i mean, however i want it so that it will link that cell in whatever sheet the formula is in. for example, lets say my sheet is named sheet22, and i clicked insert link on a1, and chose to link it to cell d5, so now when i click a1, it will take me to d5. after making the link the formula will automatically come out looking like this sheet22!d5. which means if i was to duplicate the sheet, and go to the duped sheet, the new name of the sheet will be copy of sheet 22, and the formula will still be sheet22!d5.... taking me to the original sheet when clicked.

Comment: Please provide the code that takes you to a linked cell upon clicking on another cell

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of using menu, ¸`Insert->Insert Link`, use the [HYPERLINK](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313?hl=en) formula. You can easy get the destination URL if you click on the cell, right mouse click and select "Get link to this cell".
2. Use the script below to duplicate the active sheet

   function duplicateActiveSheet() {
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
   const activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet()

   const newSheet=activeSheet.copyTo(ss)
   const ff = activeSheet.getDataRange().getFormulas().map(row=>row.map(f=>{
   if(f.match("^=HYPERLINK\(.*#gid=" + activeSheet.getSheetId())){
   return f.replaceAll(/#gid=(\d+)/g, "#gid="+newSheet.getSheetId())
   } else{
   return f
   }
   }))
   newSheet.getRange(1,1,ff.length, ff[0].length).setFormulas(ff)
   }